# Estimate G matrix in MARSS function

Tags: r

How do you estimate a G matrix for an ARMA(2,1) model with MARSS function? In that function it is fixed, but I have to estimate it.

```
B1 = matrix(list(0, "phi2", 1, "phi1"),2,2)
U1 = matrix(0,2,1)
Q1=matrix(list(0,0,0,"s2"),2,2)
Z1 = matrix(list('theta',1), 1, 2)
A1 = matrix(0,1,1)
R1 = matrix(0,1,1)
G1 = matrix(list(0,.5,0,1), 2, 2)
pi1=matrix(0,2,1); V1=diag(1,2) 
model.list=list(B=B1,U=U1, G=G1, Q=Q1,Z=Z1,A=A1,R=R1,x0=pi1,V0=V1,tinitx=1)

fit2 = MARSS(Y, model=model.list, method="BFGS")
```

I tried that code but it does not work!

Comment: Have you specified Y?

Comment: Yes i simulated Y like an ARMA(2,1) with AR parameter (.6, -.3), MA parms (-.5) and sigma = .2. Specifying Z like before i'm able to estimate MA parm with MARSS but i'm not sure that is the right way to do it. I need a generalization for an ARMA(p,q) by using MARSS function.